# Common methods efficient handling

Tags: c#, oop

I'm working out on a common method that does the same thing (for now) but may eventually require expansion in the future.

Say this method is `GetProducts()` that's being called in the home page and products page.

So my code goes like:

```
class HomePage
{
    public List<BaseInfo> LoadHomePage()
    {
         List<BaseInfo> baseInfo = new List<BaseInfo>();
         baseInfo.Add(GetProducts(5));

         return baseInfo;
    }

    public Products GetProducts(int count)
    {
         return apiProducts().Take(count).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then, in another class file:

```
class ProductsPage
{
    public List<BaseInfo> LoadProductPage()
    {
       List<BaseInfo> baseInfo = new List<BaseInfo>();
       baseInfo.Add(GetProducts(100));

       return baseInfo;
    }

    public Products GetProducts(int count)
    {
        return apiProducts().Take(count).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now, I thought of moving this `GetProducts()` to a common class file and inherit that on `HomePage` and `ProductsPage`.

```
class CommonMethods
{
   public Products GetProducts(int count)
   {
       return apiProducts().Take(count).ToList();
   }
}
```

Inheritance:

```
class HomePage : CommonMethods 

class ProductsPage: CommonMethods
```

But when time comes that I need to modify `GetProducts` for a specific purpose on Product page and don't want to affect `HomePage`, what's the best approach to do that? I want to avoid breaking other page/s because I'm changing a common method.

I tried the idea of making `GetProducts()` virtual and override the method on `ProductsPage`. That would work but I'm still thinking if there's a much better approach here. Are there any design patterns I can consider?

**EDIT:**

The main issue I'm trying to avoid is by having a common method, I don't want to break functionalities on home and products pages when I'm making changes to this `GetProducts()`;

For example, on HomePage, I only need 2 data (ID and Name)

Then on ProductsPage, I want to extend the returned data, say price, qty, etc.
sample way to do below, but I'm looking for a better solution:

```
public Products GetProducts(int count, string page)
    {
        if(page == "Home")
               return apiProducts().Select(x => new Products { Id = x.id, Name = x.name, Name = x.name }).Take(count).ToList();  
        elseif (page == "Products")  
               return apiProducts().Select(x => new Products { Id = x.id, Name = x.name, Name = x.name, Price = x.price, Qty = x.qty }).Take(count).ToList();  
    }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: This is not what inheritance is for. You need to look into "separation of concerns", make a class that's responsible for retrieving the products and then pass that class to both "Pages" (in their constructors for example).

Comment: Is this your real code? It looks like `GetProducts` should already return a `List<BaseInfo>` and what you have here won't compile.

Comment: Inheritance has drawbacks even for its intended purpose as a mechanism for polymorphism. Inheritance should definitely not be thought of as a mechanism for code reuse. IMO, beginning programmers should not even know about inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance is not always the answer. Sometimes a simple helper like below can do it

```
internal static class ProductsHelper // -- STATIC
{
    // generic method that will work for all products 
    public static List<T> GetProducts<T>(IEnumerable<T> products, int count)
    {
        return products.Take(count).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SyntaxError925 as far as reusability goes, what can be more reusable than generics?

Comment: Appreciate that. How about if I plan to change the behavior of GetProducts()specifically for ProductsPage say return desc,price,qty etc. and keep HomePage unaffected (just product id and name). I think common method is no longer valid in that case

Comment: @SyntaxError925 Sure. My answer is all about reusability. If you have lists of different types, you can apply same logic using helper classes and generics. For example, you build a car and you need to supply body parts. you call `GetPart<Door>(_alldoors, "red", 4)` Then you call `GetPart<Hood>(_allHoods, "red", 1)`. This is pure reusability. But if you have specific needs in each different class you do it there.After all your `products` come from somewhere. Usually you inject it into constructor of your class as done in the other answer, you just write class-specific code in your class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use decomposition and move your `GetProducts` method to another class. For example `ProductsRepository`
Then you'll just need to inject your `ProductsRepository` to your `HomePage` and `ProductsPage` classes using constructor injection. Like this:

```
class ProductsPage
{
    private ProductsRepository _rep;
    public ProductsPage(ProductsRepository rep)
    {
       _rep=rep;
    }

    public List<BaseInfo> LoadProductPage()
    {
       List<BaseInfo> baseInfo = new List<BaseInfo>();
       baseInfo.Add(_rep.GetProducts(100));

       return baseInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate that. How about if I plan to change the behavior of GetProducts()specifically for ProductsPage say return desc,price,qty etc. and keep HomePage unaffected (just product id and name). I think common method is no longer valid in that case